# Remove white space and indent code in Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: dreamweaver

Ive inherited some code which has loads of randomly placed spaces and line breaks. With Dreamweaver CS5 is it possible to clean up the code so its nicely indent like this?:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Come to think of it can any free editor do this if DW cant?

Comment: As techie007 says, DW can probably do it itself. If not, [arachnophilia](http://www.arachnoid.com/arachnophilia/index.php) and, naturally, emacs come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver has code formatting built into it.  Check `Commands > Clean Up HTML`, and/or it may be `Commands > Apply Source Formatting`.  I'm not sure which off-hand as I don't have a copy of CS5 in front of me to check. :)

More information is available in the Help files at help.adobe.com.  Specifically [Dreamweaver / Optimizing and debugging code](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7ba2a.html).